# "Knocked up" to mean "woken up"

Tags: british-english, slang

I'm reading some Sherlock Holmes stories (don't judge - it's good vacation reading) and Conan Doyle has Holmes saying things like "Sorry to knock you up, Watson..." which I'm finding very... odd.  From the context I'm gathering that it means "wake up," but my head immediately goes to the modern American meaning of "impregnate."

Is "knock up" ever used with this meaning anymore?  And if not, did it disappear around the time that the pregnancy meaning became common, or did it vanish on its own?

Comment: Don't ever apologize for reading Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: If you offered to knock someone up (as Sherlock meant), you'd have a 50/50 chance of being understood depending on your audience, but you should expect a smirk in either case ;)

Comment: Be glad he didn't ejaculate.

Comment: @Sam: Another great question in the making. . .

Comment: @Sam: ‘They had proceeded thus gropingly two or three miles further when on a sudden Clare became conscious of some vast erection close in his front, rising sheer from the grass. They had almost struck themselves against it.
"What monstrous place is this?" said Angel.’

Comment: This reminds me of a British friend of a friend who, while visiting said American friend, leaned across the bar and asked in a voice which carried to virtually everyone present "do you mind if I pinch a fag?"  He got his cigarette, and a lot of funny looks.

Comment: @PSU - or, I only use fags to have something to put in my mouth?

Comment: @PSU - I had the experience of an Aussie asking me that..in the 80's in [The Deep South](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_South). Once I figured out what he was asking, a quick explanation was in order in the interests of his continued health.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Google *n*-grams viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/) suggests that the “impregnate” sense became dominant in the US around the 1940’s, but that in British English, other meanings were more common until at least the 1990’s.

This is based on comparing the relative frequencies of `knocked her up` vs. `knocked him up`.  It seems reasonable to conclude that when the “impregnate” meaning becomes dominant, `knocked her up` should become much more frequent than `knocked him up`.  The results for this in the “American English” corpus show this shift happening between the ’30s and ’60s, since which time `knocked him up` has been much less common:

[image: “knocked him up” vs. “knocked her up”, American English, 1800–2000]

(The predominance of `knocked him up` in earlier years presumably just due to the preponderance of male characters in general.)  As one would expect, the British English corpus shows a very different pattern, with no such notable switch:

[image: “knocked him up” vs. “knocked her up”, American English, 1800–2000]

It looks like `knocked her up` may have been becoming predominant in British English in the ’90s, but this is such a small interval of the data that I’m not sure how much significance one can attach to it.

Comment: +1 for "him up" vs. "her up." I was using n-grams for my previous comments, but hadn't thought of wording it like this. It makes all the difference--especially in illustrating the shift in the American corpus. Nice work, and nice comparison.

Comment: Excellent sleuthing, @PLL. I never would have thought to disambiguate meanings as you did.

Comment: At least in the north of England there used to knocker-ups, who would go around houses knocking on windows to wake people up for early factory shifts.

Answer (score 12):

This is a difference between American and British English. In England if you knock someone up you get them out of bed. In America you usually have to get them *into* bed to knock them up (unless you're both in high school, in which case you will have to tilt the seat back in your parents' car). And by "them" I mean women only, because it's still the case that only women can get pregnant. But you can knock up anybody you want in Britain — how awesome is that?

Comment: So do the British *never* use "knocked up" to mean "made pregnant"?

Comment: Like many originally American expressions, it is understood here, probably because encountered in American films and TV; and I wouldn't be surprised if some people are using it. I don't think it's common.

Comment: There is an additional specialised meaning in UK political circles.  "Knocking up" is the process of getting the supporters you have identified in the previous weeks of campaigning to actually go to the polling station and vote.  It derives from the "knocking on doors" meaning but has extended beyond that.  "Telephone knock-ups" are increasingly common, for example.

Comment: @Rhodri: Are any of these other meanings still used, or understood: [to build](http://books.google.com/books?id=4gbOAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22knock%20up%22&pg=PA356#v=onepage&q=%22knock%20up%22&f=false), [to cook](http://books.google.com/books?id=xHIAAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22knock%20up%22&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q=%22knock%20up%22&f=false), [to tire](http://books.google.com/books?id=43wBAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22knock%20up%22&pg=PA423#v=onepage&q=%22knock%20up%22&f=false), [to score](http://books.google.com/books?id=Nh0GAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22knocked%20up%22&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q=%22knocked%20up%22&f=false) (in cricket)?

Comment: @Callithumpian: "to score (in cricket)," definitely. The others, less so: I see "knock up" in the sense of "create" fairly often, but would normally use "knock together" or "knock out" myself. The sense of "to tire" is a new one on me, but probably related to "knock out" as "render unconscious".

Comment: “Knocked up” meaning “tired” was certainly still current when I was a lad in York in the 1990’s… but we were also familiar enough with the “impregnate” sense that the ambiguity was the source of many jokes.

Comment: As an American, I didn't understand this answer at all, but I do agree wholeheatedly with the last sentence, so +1. :-)

Answer (score 6):

> *Knock up* is 1660s in sense of "arouse by knocking at the door;" however it is little used in this sense in Amer.Eng., where the phrase means "get a woman pregnant" (1813)....

—[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=knock)

So I guess it's a safe bet that, by the early-mid-1800s, *knock up* lacked the "wake up" meaning in the States. Google Books and the BYU corpora are your friends, though, if you want to look for specific dates of usage.

**Update:** [Another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18661), q.v., has examined Google Books, with the result that my guessed safe bet was a bad guess after all.

Comment: Is it really safe to assume the “wake up” meaning was lost in AmE that early, just because the “impregnate” meaning had appeared by then?  Often multiple meanings can persist in parallel for a long time, especially since there’s been much geographical variation within AmE at times.

Comment: It had appeared by 1813. I'm no etymologist, but I guess it's a safe bet that the "wake up" meaning was gone by 1840ish. Just a guess, though. Like I said, citations will prove it one way or the other.

Comment: Can't believe I hadn't connected "knock up" = "knocking on a door + wake up."

Comment: @msh: Using Google Books, I found _knock up_ as "to wake up" or "to tire out, use up" as predominate all the way up to at least the late 1950s.

Comment: @Callithumpian, I'm not surprised — if you didn't look in American books specifically. Did you?

Comment: @msh: Good point. I thought so at first, but after a closer look it seems most of the later references were originally British but reprinted in the U.S. I even found [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=PbHgeZ1BCCsC&dq=%22knocked%20up%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22knocked%20up%22&f=false) 1854 account of an American hearing the phrase as "used up" in London for the first time. Still, in the States, it seems _knocked up_ didn't commonly mean "pregnant" until the 1930s.

Comment: @Callithumpian, @msh210: the Google n-grams viewer, which allows one to discriminate between American and British English, strongly confirms what Callithumpian suggests; see my answer for details.

Comment: Given that British English happily accomodates multiple meanings including "impregnate", "rouse", "improvise", etc., why should Americans be likely to "lose" earlier meanings when new ones come along? It's not like there'd normally be any doubt about which sense was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Used in the "wake up" sense in New Zealand until the 1970s. *Knocker upper* was a profession in Victorian England before alarm clocks.  See Dickens' *Hindle Wakes*. Another example of TV pollution of the language by "yanks" — like *stick shift* for "gear lever" and *SUV* for "4×4".

Comment: I think *4x4* was originally a US term. And you can't really blame Americans for speaking like Americans, you should be blaming the local TV channels for showing American programmes!

Comment: _4x4_ implied four-wheel drive, which is no longer ubiquitous in SUVs.

Comment: Backing up @AndrewLazarus ... 4x4 literally means your vehicle has four wheel drive. Some cars have that, as well as some pick-up trucks. An SUV is a motor vehicle built on a truck base that is not a pickup due to the entire storage area being enclosed and accessible from the inside, and is not a van. An SUV does not have to have four-wheel-drive, and many don't. I have trouble believing the UK uses "4x4" to desginate vehicles that don't actually have four-wheel-drive. If they do, I submit that it is they who have "polluted the language" in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I heard a Scottish friend of ours ask someone if they could "knock up some brownies" the other day. Of course, she wanted them to bake a batch of brownies, but ... I'm in Canada, and everyone else (including me) started giggling like schoolchildren, and the expression on her face when she figured out what she'd just said was *priceless*.

So, this was a rather long-winded way of saying that I think it doesn't actually mean pregnant in the UK, or at least, that's a less common meaning than the other ones.

Comment: For those who don't know and thus might not fully get this post, [brownies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_(Girl_Guides)) are the 7-10 year old version of the [Girl Scouts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_Scouts_of_the_USA).

Answer (score 0):

I'm British. We used the term *knocked up* frequently when I was growing up in the 70's and 80's to mean a girl who had gotten pregnant. I am told that it is derived from the term *prima nocta*, a medieval lord's right to bed his serf's virgin daughters, but this may be apocryphal. The older generation used the term to mean wake someone up; don't know when the meaning switched but even when we were watching comedy shows in the 70's, e.g., *Are You Being Served*, this was one of the funny nudge nudge wink wink lines.

Answer (score 0):

*Is "knock up" ever used with this meaning anymore? And if not, did it disappear around the time that the pregnancy meaning became common, or did it vanish on its own?*

The semantic factor is apparent, writes the linguist,
Leonard Bloomfield,in the disfavoring of speech-forms that are homonymous
with tabu-forms. ... In America, **knocked up** is a tabu-
form for "rendered pregnant"; for this reason, the phrase
is not used in the British sense "tired, exhausted." In
older French and English there was a word, French con-
nil, connin, English coney, for "rabbit"; in both lan-
guages this word died out because it resembled a word
/ that was undera_ tabu ofindecency. For the same reason,
( rooster and donkey are replacing cock and ass in Ameri-
can English. In such cases there is little real ambiguity,
but some hearers react nevertheless to the powerful
stimulus of the tabu-word; having called forth ridicule
or embarrassment, the speaker avoids the innocent homo-
r nym. It is a remarkable fact that the tabu-word itself has
a much tougher life than the harmless homonym.12
Yes, good words fall into disrepute, while the tabooed
words are tough and resistant. -The anatomy of dirty words. . Sagarin, Edward, (1962)