# Spelling of "moustache"

Tags: orthography

This has always confused me. I've always spelled it "moustache", but my browser's spell checker claims the correct spelling is "mustache". From what I've seen around the Internet, people seem to use both.

What is the proper spelling? Are both acceptable?

Comment: If you’re using Chrome it might be worth noting that it apparently has a bug that will cause it to always use the American spelling even if British spelling is activated in the preferences. At least that’s the case for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems like a good one for [Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/).

It looks like in British English *moustache* has always been the preferred spelling.

[image: "moustache" vs. "mustache," British English, 1800-2008]

In American English, it's been more of a battle with *mustache* now in the lead.

[image: "moustache" vs. "mustache," American English, 1800-2008]

So here's a combined view. Both are contenders in the English-speaking world, but clear preferences exist on opposite sides of the pond.

[image: "moustache" vs. "mustache", English corpus, 1800-2008]

(Have to wonder if the peaks and valleys correspond to mustaches going in and out of vogue.)

Comment: I wondered about the same explanation of the peaks and valleys when I was doing the same searches for my answer!  If only there were an equivalent of corpus searches for fashions in facial hair, to test this hypothesis…

Comment: @PLL: Maybe [this](http://www.americanmustacheinstitute.org/MustacheHistory.aspx) could shed some light :{ It did give me the idea that certain peaks could be explained by famous and/or notorious mustached men (e.g. Hitler and the WWII peak?) Congrats on your quicker answer, btw. I took too long inserting images for the first time--inspired by your ["knocked up"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18568/knocked-up-to-mean-woken-up/18661#18661) answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Both spellings are correct.**  Which is more standard will depend where you are.  *Mustache* is somewhat more common in American English, and has been since the 1940’s.  *Moustache* is older (being the original French spelling, from which the English word is derived) and still much more common in British English, to the extent that *mustache* may be seen as an Americanism; but *mustache* is now gaining some ground in Britain too.

(Sources: [Google *N*-grams viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=moustache%2Cmustache&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) for usage, and the [OED](http://www.oed.com) for etymology.)

Comment: Love the nGrams! Just did favorite,favourite in BE and AE :)

Answer (score 2):

*Moustache* is a variant, possibly on its way out.

But don't be intimidated by the squiggly lines in your browser's text fields. If you know a word is spelled right, go ahead and use it. Most of the time when I can't decide on a spelling it's a variant anyway. Browsers just aren't that smart.

Answer (score 1):

*Moustache* was definitely the spelling in mind when [Movember](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movember) was coined:

> Movember (a portmanteau word from moustache and "November") is an
>   annual, month-long event involving the growing of moustaches during
>   the month of November to raise awareness of prostate cancer and other
>   male cancer and associated charities. The Movember Foundation runs the
>   Movember charity event, housed at Movember.com The goal of Movember is
>   to "change the face of men's health."

The Welsh word for November is *Tachwedd*, so in Wales Movember is called *Tache-wedd* - a really pleasing bilingual coinage, well done whoever thought that up!

Answer (score 0):

The proper spelling depends on which English you use. The "mustache" spelling (which just had a wavy, red line underneath, when I typed it) is American spelling. The "moustache" spelling is English spelling.

This is demonstrated in the following link http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/moustache?q=moustache , which says (US usually **mustache**).