# he pregnate my daughter and he pregnated my daughter

Tags: expressions

i have being trying endlessly to think up something positive about this expression

which of these is correct?

He pregnate my daughter

He pregnated my daughter

Comment: They are both positively incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

He impregnated my daughter

Or -

- My daughter is expecting.
- My daughter is going to have a baby
- Congratulations! My daughter is expecting!

Answer (score 2):

Neither is. The verb is *impregnate*.

Then, there are two possibilities:

- He impregnates my daughter. (Present tense - unlikely to be heard)
- He impregnated my daughter. (Past tense)

The positive part of the expression is of course

> I am going to be a granddad.

Answer (score 2):

Merriam Webster lists "[pregnate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pregnate)" as an obsolete intransitive verb meaning "to become fertile" (*I pregnated*) and as a transitive verb meaning the same as "impregnate" (*I [im]pregnated her*).

The latter does not have an actual definition, but rather a link to "impregnate", suggesting that this is the preferred, standard term.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pregnate,impregnate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4;,pregnate;,c0;,s0;;pregnate;,c0;;Pregnate;,c0;.t4;,impregnate;,c0;,s0;;impregnate;,c0;;Impregnate;,c0) shows that usage of "pregnate" is indeed negligible compared to that of "impregnate":

[image]

(It is worth noting that this does not show the usage context. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pregnate&rlz=1C1CHWA_enCA533CA533&oq=pregnate&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0l2j69i60j69i61.1754j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) brings up plenty of hits for"pregnate" as an obvious misspelling of "pregnant"; this could be the case *even in printed books!*)

Answer (score 0):

One would say: 'He impregnated my daughter, but perhaps more commonly, 'He made my daughter pregnant'.

Answer (score 0):

Informally: He *knocked up* my daughter. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18568/knocked-up-to-mean-woken-up).

*He impregnated my daughter* sounds like the sort of thing you'd say before directing a henchman to dispose of the lifeless body of her erstwhile suitor.

Comment: There are a whole multiplicity of informal ways of saying it, on a scale of polite to thoroughly obscene, depending to an extent on where you come from.

Answer (score 0):

Informally also: He put my daughter *in the family way*.

> http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+family+way

Comment: Certainly frequently used British idiom - less so in America I suspect.