# What is the primary meaning of 'knocked up'

Tags: etymology

There seem to be several meanings;

Awoken in the morning;
Made pregnant;
Put together/prepared quickly or on the fly;
Made tired/worn out.

I have never heard of this last meaning which (used earlier by my father) needless to say was the one that nearly started a very fraught conversation!

What is the primary or dominant meaning?
Many thanks

Comment: Why does there have to be one primary meaning? I think your second and third meanings are equally dominant.

Answer (score 4):

While 'Knocked Up' doesn't usually refer to 'Made Tired/Worn Out', [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18568/knocked-up-to-mean-woken-up) might be somewhat relevant to what you're looking for- "primary meaning of Knocked Up". As you will see, the phrase 'Knocked Up' has different primary meanings over different geographical areas.

In short, other than the primary meaning we all know, here are the other(relatively less used) meanings you're looking for(cited from the above link)-

> This is a difference between American and British English. In England
>   if you knock someone up you get them out of bed

and

> Knock up is 1660s in sense of "arouse by knocking at the door;"
>   however it is little used in this sense in Amer.Eng., where the phrase
>   means "get a woman pregnant" (1813)....

-[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=knock)

Comment: Can you please quote for us the relevant information from that link? We expect on this site for answers to include the information themselves and not just link to it. (Please include the link as well, we need sources for quotes too!)

Answer (score -4):

It only means to be made pregnant, at least in modern usage.

It is possible that "knocked *out*" means tired/worn out, but I haven't really heard that used.

Also, *knocked about* means to have gone through a tough, difficult or stressful time. *About* here means "here and there" not "in regards to".

Comment: Really? - I knocked up a bookcase once. I hope nobody finds out..

Comment: In British English, "What time do you want to be knocked up?" still means "How early tomorrow morning do you want me to come and wake you up?"

Comment: @Erik It's not that usual nowadays.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - *J'accuse* the invention of the alarm clock...